# R- Searching list of codes across multiple columns and returning appropriate value from different but associated columns

Tags: r

Basically what I am looking to do, is search across ‘incode’ columns in to find a code that matches a predetermined list (e.g. 53 and 55) – If a code is there I want to return the ‘location’ code from the matching ‘location’ column and add this vector to the dataset. It is possible that the same row would have multiple code matches, so I would just like the first one that matches (from left to right).

As an added challenge I would like to specify the surgery codes (53,55) AND columns to search (2-4) AND the columns to lookup and replace the values (5-7) by their names (incode1-3, and location1-3) rather than by column number.

My thoughts are such:

I need to use apply to do this row by row in the dataset.

I need to use the ‘match’ function to determine which row (first) from the incode columns has a matching code

I then need to use this column indicator to specify which column of the location codes I should return the value from.

I have struggled with match and apply and have yet to find something that works. Any recommendations welcomed, and I have included some sample and desired output data below.

```
# list of columns to search
search <- (paste("incode",seq(1:3),sep=""))

# list of columns to return value from 
return <- (paste("location",seq(1:3),sep=""))

# codes to search for
codes <- c("^53","^55")

# example data
id = c(1,2,3,4)
incode1 =c("53","45", "55", "45")
incode2 =c("53", NA, NA, "45")
incode3 =c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
location1 =c(1,2,1,1)
location2 =c(1, NA, NA, 2)
location3 =c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
data_example <-  data.frame(id,incode1,incode2,incode3,location1,location2,location3)

# desired data
indicator = c(1,NA,1,2)
data_desired <-  data.frame(id,incode1,incode2,incode3,location1,location2,location3,indicator)
```

Edit 1: My attempt but still not working

```
data$indicator <- apply(data[(match((paste0('\\b(',paste
(codes,collapse="|"),),')')))',data[,search], nomatch=NA)),],1,)
```

I have not figured out where to specify the columns to return that values from  (return) though I know this must be applied to data[] somewhere....

If you have any suggestions they would be most welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: How come all your quotes are curly `“”` instead of regular `"`? This doesn't run for me.

Comment: @Molx sorry - copy and pasted in - has been fixed.

Comment: for id=4, why isn't the desired result `NA` as there are no values of 53 or 55

Comment: also is there a reason why you're storing this data as strings and not numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I am understanding your question correctly, then the following should work after a few changes to your variables declared.

```
### i made all the data numbers instead of strings
id = c(1,2,3,4)
incode1 =c(53,45, 55, 45)
incode2 =c(53, NA, NA, 45)
incode3 =c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
location1 =c(1,2,1,1)
location2 =c(1, NA, NA, 2)
location3 =c(NA, NA, NA, NA)
data_example <-  data.frame(id,incode1,incode2,incode3,location1,location2,location3)

### i changed the name of 'return' to "locations" because 
### return is generally used to return a value in R... 
### you don't use it as a variable name
search <- (paste("incode",seq(1:3),sep=""))
locations <- (paste("location",seq(1:3),sep=""))
codes <- c(53,55)

### separated into two dataframes so we can use sapply
### because in a sense our incode values are the decision data
### and the locationdata is the map we want to pull values from
incodedata <- data_example[,search]
locationdata <- data_example[,locations]
### using a combination of sapply and ifelse we can do what you desire
indicator <- sapply(1:nrow(incodedata),function(m) 
  ifelse(any(!is.na(z <- match(codes,incodedata[m,]))),locationdata[m,z[!is.na(z)][1]],NA))

data_example$indicator <- indicator
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to my question! I tried this just now, and I got all NA's for the indicator. I think the complication is that I need to search for codes that include both characters and numbers - and I just know what each code should start with (not the code in its' entirety). I have search for code as follows `codes <- c("53", "55")` and then to put a wildcard on it: `codes <- paste0('\\b(',paste(unlist(codes),collapse="|"),')')` Any recommendations are welcomed, thanks again.

Comment: my method should work. the issue is with the factor levels of the dataframe if you are using strings and numbers versus numbers alone.

you just need to figure out a way to make `incodedata[m,]` values be correct when they are strings. `as.character(incodedata[1,])` for example is returning values that are not originally entered

Comment: Thank you. Got it working by changing incode data and locationdata to characters as follows `incodedata[] <- lapply(incodedata, as.character)`